# Error: Unclassifiable statement (decode) on Fortran code

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a Windows DLL came from a FORTRAN code.
The DLL is working but I need to change it and port to Linux.

Now I'm trying to wrap it into a Java code using [this](https://github.com/Gjacquenot/DemoJavaFortranInterface/blob/master/Makefile) and trying to compile with gfortran too.

I'm facing an issue like `Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)` but searching around  I read this error is too generic and related to many things, none of them related to my code (or I think so).

Here is the problematic code:

```
...
character*2 di,mi
character*4 ai
...
integer*2 dia_ini, mes_ini, ano_ini
...

decode (2, '(i2)', mi ) mes_ini
decode (2, '(i2)', di ) dia_ini
decode (4, '(i4)', ai ) ano_ini

...
```

All `decode` lines are giving error at beginning of line (the "1" is pointing below the `d` of "decode")

One thing I can't understand is `di,mi' and 'ai' are in parameter list too:

`Subroutine PREVISAO (di,mi,ai)`

Is this allowed on Fortran? Aren't the initial values on parameters lost?

The original files have a `.f90` extension and have only `subroutine` blocks.

Comment: Sounds still like a problem of fixed form versus free form code. Does your file still have the `.f90` extension when not try it, otherwise it sounds a bit like a missing compilation option in your tool-chain. Possible workaround might be to insert 6 spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: [`encode` and `decode` are not Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22182242/3157076).

Comment: @francescalus are you sure? So it must be very similar.  All until this line (635)  goes fine.

Comment: docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn87/index.html

Comment: From that page "ENCODE and DECODE are not in the FORTRAN 77 Standard".  As you've tagged [tag:gfortran] the link given in answer to the other question cover gfortran's support for this extension.  You should use a compiler such as Oracle's or rewrite the code using supported code (internal reads, perhaps).

Comment: @francescalus interesting... I know nothing about fortran. I hope it can be easy to dicover the standard used here. Any chance to the Oracle's one can compile it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, DECODE (and ENCODE) is not part of the Fortran standard, and GFortran does not support this particular extension. In the GFortran manual you can find examples how to convert ENCODE and DECODE into standard Fortran constructs using internal READ/WRITE statements: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ENCODE-and-DECODE-statements.html

Comment: Ok but what if other non-standard statements (if exists) ? Would be better to use correct compiler if I can find it. I know nothing about FORTRAN and I'm afraid to mess all the code if change a thing ( the butterfly effect )

Comment: I don't have any details of whatever code you're trying to compile, so how would I know? Maybe it's enough to fix the DECODE/ENCODE stuff, maybe not?